# What's the word for "life" but with emphasis on the positiveness of life?

Tags: word-choice

I know that 人生 is used for “human life”, and 生命 for “life” in the biological sense.
But I want to express that life (whatever) is something good, something positive and I don´t know if it's possible.

Comment: You can't just ask about word choice without providing a context. You may say 美しき生涯/人生/一生を送る, not 生命/命を送る in the same sense.

Answer (score 1):

What about いのち (and the kana spelling here is intentional):

> 盗人が来るのは、ただ盗んだり、殺したり、滅ぼしたりするだけのためです。わたしが来たのは、羊がいのちを得、またそれを豊かに持つためです。　（ヨハネ福音の10:10）

My other thought is ライフ in the katakana.

My sensibilities could be off on both of those since I'm not a native speaker, but I get the impression that the 和製英語 has a positive feel to it and the other can mean life in the sense you would want to call good better than 生命 or 人生.

Comment: I made a litlle research and I found that in all the ecclesiastical trnslations is used いのち instead of 命. There is a difference of meaning for use the kana spelling instead of the kanji?